# Eclipse Starts building workspace every time after I do workspace search

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I am using Eclipse for my one of the Java project and below is the issue I am facing.

When I do workspace search (CTRL+H) in Mac, it starts building entire workspace immediately after search was done.

Since it's a huge project which has multiple modules, it takes lot of time to build the workspace every time.

Can anyone suggest what setting should be setup for this to avoid issue?

Comment: I think there is a setting to turn off build automatically in the Preferences. I remember doing this when I worked with Ecilipse. Can you try that?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using ?

Comment: @Sambit It's Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

Comment: Can you try to use the latest one and check ?

Comment: Don't see the Issue after uncheck "Build Automatically", but still strange why global search makes Eclipse to build again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Project. Go to `Project` menu and uncheck `Build Automatically`